# How to add HTML tags automatically to different line in a .txt file in sublime text?

Tags: html, regex, file, sublimetext3

So I have a .txt file with almost 10000 lines, each of which is seperate, and in order. It's a question bank.

The format is like this

```
1 Question
2 Answer 1
3 Answer 2
4 Answer 3
5 Answer 4
6 Answer 5
7 Question
8 Answer 1
9 Answer 2
10 Answer 3
11 Answer 4
12 Answer 5
and so forth..
```

My question is - I want to select all the answer choices in the document and add HTML tags to the start and end of those lines in the document. How can I do this without doing it manually? I also want to select only the 1,7,13 lines to select the questions only and give them seperate html tags at the start and ends of those lines.

Comment: What separates a line with a question from one with an answer? (I assume in your example, the words "Question" and "Answer" are only placeholders for the actual text.)

Comment: It's just how the document was given to me. There's 10k lines, and there is one question line followed by five answer lines. And it repeats just like that. `1 = Question, 2,3,4,5,6 = answers // 7 = question, 8,9,10,11,12 = answers, 13 = question` and so forth. Yes that is correct ClasG, it's a plain txt document and that is placeholder text.

Comment: Is it something like [this](https://regex101.com/r/etfUGt/1) you're after? (It assumes there, as you state, always is one line with a question followed by 5 lines with answers.)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Printing Questions:

```
for i in `seq 1 6 30`; do sed -n "${i}p" sample.txt; done
```

Output

```
1 Question
7 Question
```

Adding HTML tags to Questions only:

```
for i in `seq 1 6 30`; do sed -i -E  "${i}s/(^.*)/<questiontag>\1<\/questiontag>/g" sample.txt; done
```

Adding HTML tags to Answers only:

```
for i in `seq 1 6 30`; do qs=$(($i+1)); qe=$(($i+5)) ; sed -i -E  "${qs},${qe}s/(^.*)/<answertag>\1<\/answertag>/g" sample.txt; done
```

Contents of `sample.txt`:

```
<questiontag>1 Question</questiontag>
<answertag>2 Answer 1</answertag>
<answertag>3 Answer 2</answertag>
<answertag>4 Answer 3</answertag>
<answertag>5 Answer 4</answertag>
<answertag>6 Answer 5</answertag>
<questiontag>7 Question</questiontag>
<answertag>8 Answer 1</answertag>
<answertag>9 Answer 2</answertag>
<answertag>10 Answer 3</answertag>
<answertag>11 Answer 4</answertag>
<answertag>12 Answer 5</answertag>
```

You will need to change `30` with a number of your choice like `100000` or you can replace it with `$(wc -l < sample.txt)` which will return the number of lines of sample.txt. e.g.

```
for i in `seq 1 6 $(wc -l < sample.txt)`; do sed -n "${i}p" sample.txt; done
```

Comment: Is this with PHP? How is this meant to be used?

Comment: you can use it directly from the command line (terminal) on linux or macOS as these are shell commands

Answer (score 2):

I'm assuming you are looking for something like this...

Match exact pattern

```
\d+\sQuestion(.*$)\s\d+\sAnswer(.*)\s\d+\sAnswer(.*)\s\d+\sAnswer(.*)\s\d+\sAnswer(.*)\s\d+\sAnswer(.*)
```

Replace with an HTML equivalent

```
<h1>$1</h1>\n<ol>\n<li>$2</li>\n<li>$3</li>\n<li>$4</li>\n<li>$5</li>\n<li>$6</li>\n</ol>
```

([regex101](https://regex101.com/r/etfUGt/2))

Answer (score 0):

### Method 1

The best method to do what you are trying is probably to write some code that reads the text file line by line to change the code.

Assuming `n` = line number

```
if((n-1)%6 === 0) // Question
else // Answer
```

### Method 2

From what I can see there are two line formats.

- Questions begin with a number and end with new line/carriage return.
- Answers begin with a number and end with a number followed by new line/carriage return.

Assuming any character apart from new line could be inside a question or answer

Regex to identify all questions: `/^(\d+\s)(.+?(?<!\d))$/gm`
Regex to identify all answers: `/^(\d+\s)(.+)(\s\d+)$/gm`

*This assumes that no questions end in a digit.*

---

#### Code example in PHP

I can't test this right now but it should be similar to the following code.

```
$file = 'my/file.txt'
$contents = file($file);
$result = [];

$regexes = [
    'question' => [
        'regex' => '/^(\d+\s.+?\s?(?<!\d))$/gm',
        'replace' => '<div>$2</div>'
    ],
    'answer' => [
        'regex' => '/^(\d+\s)(.+)(\s\d+)$/gm',
        'replace' => '<div>$2</div>'
    ]
];
foreach($contents as $line) {
    foreach($regexes as $regex) {
        if(preg_match($regex['regex'], $line)) {
            $result[] = preg_replace($regex['regex'], $regex['replace'], $line);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Mind me asking why the downvote? I provide two method logics that work to change the text in the text file. The regex works according to the specifications given by the OP.

Comment: It wasn't me downvoting, I'm wondering why you were downvoted too!